# Algorithm to sort a list L of n positive integer keys which need not to be distinct. Should have complexity of O(n+N) where N = maxL(i) - minL(i)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, quicksort, mergesort

Algorithm to sort a list L of n positive integer keys which need not to be distinct. Should have complexity of `O(n+N)` where `N = maxL(i) - minL(i)`?

I tried to something like merge sort, but that gives me `O(nlogn)`. I am given `O(N)` extra space so it doesn't have to be `O(n)` complexity. However, i don't know if my mergesort-like algorithm is allowed to take a multiplicity of log n times. please help?

Comment: If this is homework you should add the homework tag. Also, wikipedia has a page that lists complexity for various sorting algorithms at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm.

Comment: @JamieSee, I believe the homework tag has been deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, @Iserni. I was unaware of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm you describe seems to be a variant of the "count sort" (I was taught it as "librarian sort", *ordinamento del libraio*)

This is the pseudocode from Wikipedia:

```
''' allocate an array Count[0..k] ; initialize each array cell to zero ; THEN '''
for each input item x:
    Count[key(x)] = Count[key(x)] + 1
total = 0
for i = 0, 1, ... k:
    c = Count[i]
    Count[i] = total
    total = total + c

''' allocate an output array Output[0..n-1] ; THEN '''
for each input item x:
    store x in Output[Count[key(x)]]
    Count[key(x)] = Count[key(x)] + 1
return Output
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

Answer (score 1):

here is my bucket sort (radix sort) implementation.

```
def _sort(_list):
    buckets=[0]*len(_list)
    for i in _list:
        i=int(i)
        assert(0<=i<len(_list))
        buckets[i]+=1
    result=[]
    for num,count in enumerate(buckets):
        result.extend([num]*count)
    return result
```

you would need to change len(_list) to max-min, and then change i=int(i) to i= i - min (and in the final result convert i to i + min

The idea is that we transform every number i to i -min. (now min=0 and max = old_max - min).
Now in our array the ith position denotes how many times number i-min occurs. We simply go through the list and increment the appropriate array position. We then go through the array in order and have the sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

best sorting algorithms (merge sort, quick sort etc.) have `O(nlogn)` complexity **however** there are some special cases. (Hint: special case for your problem is that they are all integers)

Comment: Actually, what you say is true for *in place* sorts. Being integer has little to do with it; all that's asked is that there is a comparison operator.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand what you mean. nvm people posted explicit answers anyway..

Comment: Oh, I meant that when doing `a < b`, having integers instead of floats (or strings for that matter) does not make it a "special" case. Having the possibility of using significant (O(N)) extra space, though, does.

Comment: well, if they were floats (and by float I mean something like rational numbers) I wouldn't be able to count the numbers in a given range therefore wouldn't be able to index them for bucket sort or count sort. that's how I like to remember but I guess we're talking about the same thing.